# Workaround weird Samsung Internet browser fullscreen behavior

Tags: css, media-queries, samsung-mobile

There is unusual fullscreen behavior on specific browser version/device

> (Samsung Internet 9.4.00.45, Samsung Galaxy S8 Plus)

Sometimes, when fullscreen is requested as a response to specific user gesture, the app goes full screen but top url bar remains visible (see picture). I haven't observed the same behavior on other devices or Chrome on the same device.

```
const requestFullScreen =
    document.requestFullscreen ||
    document.webkitRequestFullscreen ||
    document.mozRequestFullScreen ||
    document.msRequestFullscreen;

if (requestFullScreen) {
    return request.call(document, { navigationUI: "hide" });
}
```

Passing `{ navigationUI: "show" }` has no effect.

Is there any way to achieve flawless, all-fullscreen on this specific browser like on Chrome? It works well on the same browser on Galaxy S9.

It doesn't seem to work to match this specific alignment - fullscreen minus top bar with media query, since the browser thinks the viewport is the full screen height. Indeed, this bar overlaps document content.

[image]

Comment: The same thing was happening on my Samsung A5 with the same browser version. However, it turned out that the brower url bar was **reappearing** after a navigation, which I think is normal behaviour for this browser. I also got thrown because it appeared the screen was going blank, but I needed to set the background-color on the element which was fullscreen as the parent bg was not being inherited like on other browsers.